# Как в коде задать размер layout?

Tags: android

Есть layout, в нем есть view

```
visualizerLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

Этот layout рисуется на весь экран, как сделать так чтобы он рисовался только до размеров вписанной view.

И как сделать так чтобы вписанная в него view центрировалась по центру экрана (прямо или косвенно - не важно)

Вообще говоря, у меня layout занимает почему-то весь экран,а view занимает весь layout и таким образом тоже заполняет весь экран, а хочется чтобы layout был размером как вьюшка внутри него, и рисовался в конкретном месте, layout генерируются java кодом (не из xml).

Comment: Ничо непонятно - поподробнее пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотря где у вас layout задается, если вы xml, то вот так, а в него уже помещаете нужную вам view:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
            </LinearLayout>
```

В коде, то нужно понимать в каком контейнере у нас находится, либо использовать ViewGroup.LayoutParams, я бы лучше использовал первый вариант.
Предположим, что layout будет находится в RelativeLayout(для остальных layout'ов будет аналогично)

```
layout = new LinearLayout(context);
layout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
//и добавляете свою view в layout
layout.addView(yourView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно динамически строить UI на основании каких-то данных?
Если так то лучше сделать вложенные (читай, дочерние) view-хи в xml-лайаутах.
Потом при построении UI (например формы или какого-то другого контента) просто инфлейтить дочерние вьюхи, передавать в них нужные данные и прикреплять к корневому лайауту.